# Oracle SQL : Check for combination of values from same row from 2 columns

Tags: sql

I saw few similar queries but did not help my cause.
I have a table similar to below :

> ```
> Name             Value      Item
> ---------------------------------
> isVisible        True       123 
> isAvailable      False      123
> Qty              3          123 
> isOnline         True       123
> DeleteElig       True       123
> ```

I need to find all items which has isVisible = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtering:

```
select item
from t
where name = 'isVisible' and value = 'True';
```